# Thumbanails Not Regenerating

Tags: 9.0-pie, thumbnails

So I recently switched to a Samsung Galaxy A50 with One UI version 1.1 build over Android Version 9.

So, I've been facing an issue with thumbnails regeneration. The DCIM/.thumbnails folder keeps deleting its content next day (which I suppose is a feature to save memory). But, the problem occurs when the contents aren't able to regenerate themselves.
The gallery apps itslef is working fine and regenerating thumbs properly but not creating new thumbs in the DCIM/.thumbnails folder due to which I'm unable to post on Instagram and Reddit.

I tried clear data and clear cache on gallery, rebooted my device but it,s still no good.

Comment: If you know where the bad thumbnails are stored why don't you just delete the `DCIM/.thumbnails`folder?

Comment: I tried that, and guess what? No thumbnails are generated. Only if I click a new pic, the folder is recreated along with the thumbnail of the new pic.

Comment: If you take a new photo is the thumbnail generated directly? Can you post such an image using the apps you mentioned? If not it is clearly a bug in the apps.

Comment: Well new when I take a new photo, the thumbnails are generated. But after one day, when the phone clears thumbnails as a memory saving measure, the thumbnail won't generate now. This causes problems when I have to post a day old pics on these apps.